# How do I add an image before text to a table item which needs to be found by class?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

JS:

```js
 function add(){
      while(i < $('.tabledata').length){
          var current_val = $('.tabledata').eq(i).text();
          arr.push(current_val);
          $('.tabledata').eq(i).text() = "<img src='/flags/'" + (flagsarr[current_val].toLowerCase() + '.png') + ' width="20px" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><b>' + current_val + '</b>';
          i++;
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){ add(); });
```

current_val is a Country. flagsarr[curren_val] is the country code: eg ES (Spain).
in this case, i want to add 'es.png' before the text 'Spain' in the table.

I tried using `text()` but I realised it was a function.

Please note: there are around 200 rows in the table, each with 5 pieces of data (so 5 columns), the first being the Country. Each of the first column items share the class 'tabledata'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `each` to iterate over `tabledata` and `html()` instead of `text()` to get its content:

```
function add() {
    var $tableData = $('.tableData');
    $.each($tableData, function(index, value){
        var current_val = $(value).html();
        arr.push(current_val);
        $(value).html("<img src='/flags/'" + flagsarr[current_val].toLowerCase() + ".png'" + ' width="20px" style="margin-bottom: 2px;"><b>' + current_val + '</b>');
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){ add(); });
```

Comment: thanks, however you mixed up currentVal and current_val. When i fixed this, it doesn't like the `toLowerCase()` because `flagsarr[current_val]` is undefined.

Comment: Is `flagsarr` defined in your script? Use `console.log()` to see what `current_val` returns.

Comment: your answer is what I was looking for - it includes the `.html` part which is what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help :)